# Header and footer fixed and content fills all space between

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout for my site for a chat app. It needs to look something like this:
[image: drawing]
The point is that I don't want to body to scroll at all, just the chat area. My markup is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="chat"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: something like this ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/hFumI , remove <aside> widths, padding-left on body and negative margins

Comment: Yes, without the sidebar thats exactly what I need.

Comment: or my codepen ;) with the scroll inside content

Answer (score 1):

Using fixed positioning, you can do something like this in your CSS.
Let's say the chat section division has "chat" as its ID and that the header and footer have an height of 200px.

```
.container .header {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;

    height: 200px;
}

.container .chat {
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:200px;
    bottom:200px;

    /* For Scrollbars */
    overflow: auto;
}

.container .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;

    height: 200px;
}
```

Suggestion: you should use a "header" tag and a "footer" tag instead of "div" tags affected by css classes. Also, you should consider using absolute positioning instead of fixed positioning if you wrap the header, chat and footer inside a wrapper div so that the positions are relative to the wrapper and not the document. If you do so, don't forget to add a "position: relative" to the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is position everything absolutely, and have your main content area have an

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#main {
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 50px;
}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cM277/

Comment: Why would you use fixed. He specifically said he doesn't want the page to scroll. There is no need.

Comment: Exactly. Not the page. Fixed position is relative to the document always. If the document is never going to scroll fixed positioning doesn't do anything but act like absolute positioning.